# Проблема с реализацией классов при наследовании

Tags: c++, ооп, наследование, полиморфизм

столкнулся с проблемой реализации классов. Вкратце, я создал супер класс **Item** от которого наследовались классы **Gun**, **_Mag**, **_Ammo** и тд.

Вот картинка иерархия классов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У класса **Item** есть виртуальный метод **doItemAction** который принимает enum **eItemActions** (код определенного действия), вторым параметром **Item** и возвращаемый тип **Item**.

У всех классов в поле **private** находятся функции для метода **doItemAction**.

Данные классы:

> item.h

```
class Item
{
public:
    enum eItemActions {
        PickUp,
        Drop,
        Examinate
    };

    Item();
    Item(const int& idItem, const std::string& itemName, 
         const std::string& itemType, const float& itemWeight);

    virtual void printItemInfo();

    virtual Item* doItemAction(eItemActions ac, Item* item = nullptr);

    virtual ~Item();

private:
    // Some actions (PickUp, Drop, Examinate)

};
```

> Gun.h

```
class Gun : public Item {
public:
    Gun(const Item& item);

    enum eItemActions {
        DoDamage,
        DoAim
    };

    Item* doItemAction(eItemActions ac, Item* item = nullptr) override;

private:
    // Some actions (DoDamage, DoAim)

};
```

> gunTypes.h

```
class coldSteel final :
    public Gun 
{  
public:
    enum eItemActions {
        DoAltDamage,
    };

    coldSteel();
    coldSteel(const float& attackSpeed, _Damage* damage, const Item& item);

    void printItemInfo() override;

    Item* doItemAction(eItemActions ac, Item* item = nullptr) override;

private:
    // Some actions (DoAltDamage)

};

class fireArms final :
    public Gun
{
public:
    enum eItemActions {
        ReloadGun,
        LoadGun,
        UnloadGun
    };

    fireArms();
    fireArms(const float& Recoil, const std::string& gunCalib, const Item& Item, _Mag* mag = new _Mag());

    void printItemInfo() override;

    Item* doItemAction(eItemActions ac, Item* item = nullptr) override;

private:
    // Some actions (RealoadGun, LoadGun, UnloadGun) 

};
```

В итоге при вызове метода **doItemAction** из любого класса можно выбрать действие с помощью enum **eItemActions**. Но проблема заключается в том, что enum в методе **doItemAction** не может быть перезаписан в наследуемых классах. По этому я не могу понять как мне лучше реализовать данную систему.

Comment: Стоит ли мне просто вынести **enum eItemAction** за предел класса **Item** и просто повписывать все возможные варианты?

Comment: `eItemActions` в разных классах - это разные, никак не связанные енумераторы, оттого и проблема с `doItemAction`. А иерархия классов выглядит крайне странно. Скорее уж стоит сделать иерархию классов-действий.

Comment: Да, согласен. Я просто сделаю в каждом классе свой enum по типу **eGunAction, eItemAction** и тд. Так же добавлю в каждый клас виртуальный метод, по типу **doGunAction, doItemAction**. Так будет смотрется лучше?  Или сделать отдельный класс, как вы говорили, под сами действия, но я немного не понимаю как правильно его заимплементить.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: Если ссылатся на статью из вики. То получается в классе **Command** мы можем указать поле Item и через этот класс выполнять действия. Я так понял, к примеру взять класс **fireArms** в нём нужно указать только те методы которые с ним связаны. Я прав?

Comment: Скорее наоборот, все действия из класса Item вынести в классы команды. А классы Item сделать простыми контейнерами для свойств.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А как закрыть этот топик?

Comment: Его можно не закрывать, а запостить самоответ потом. А вообще для этого под вопросом есть соотв. кнопка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы реализовал эту схему взаимодействия таким образом:

Делаем два абстрактных класса

1. `Item` - предок всех нужных сущностей
2. `Action` - предок всех действий

У класса `Item` есть абстрактный метод `do`, который принимает параметр - объект класса `Action`.

Каждый потомок класса `Item` реализует метод `do` нужным образом в соответствии с данными, которые записаны в объекте `Action`.

Каждый потомок `Action` имеет свой набор свойств, необходимых для выполнения объектом `Item` нужного действия.

В итоге мы имеем полностью независимую систему классов, которая легко дополняется и модифицируется.

Comment: Хорошо, но если у нас есть холодное и огнистрельное оружие у них есть действие doDamage. Огнистрел будет выстреливать пулю, а холодное будет наносить дамаг.

Comment: Или вы имеете в виду от Action наследовать fireArmActions и coldSteelAction?

Comment: Можете мне немного подробнее обьяснить. Просто я думаю с данного примера что нужно сделать так, мы под каждое действие создаем класс от супер класса Action и используем его в методе do.

Comment: Да. Все верно. Если у нас есть `Холодное оружие`, то создаем класс-наследник `Item_Cold`, тоже абстрактный. В нем в методе `do` реализуем поведение общее для  холодного оружия. На вход получаем объект класса-потомка от `Action`, например `Action_Cold`, в котором передаются данные удара. И создаем еще один класс-наследник от `Item_Cold` уже реальный `Item_Cold_Knife` в котором прописываем поведение в зависимости от события `Action_Cold` которое нужно уже для ножа. Например удар рукоятью или удар лезвием. В `Action` передаем объект, кого режут. Аналогично с огнестрелом.